# Give result of multiply function minimum value of zero

Tags: function, google-sheets, minimum

Here is a run down version of [my accounting spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_yt_vVc5199hZY5BLzRa2Q6oep6LtOZJUZ9qyojxo0k/edit#gid=0).

The idea is simple: If I make profit, I pay tax; if I make no profit or have loss, I don't have to pay tax.

However, with the way the tax calculation function is set up, my net loss will always be 20% less than the actual amount. To fix this, I want to make it so that the tax value will never go below zero (or its minimum value will become `0`).

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just wrap it in an `if`.  Like `=if(C6<0,0,(C6*.2))`. It will return a zero if the value in the profit cell is less than zero.